# XCode 4.2 Source Control problems

Tags: xcode, git, version

I seem to have a major problem.  I opened up Xcode and my main view controller code seems to have been replaced with the original code, it's all gone.  All my other files have the little 'M' for modified icon next to them, this problem file however does not.  It seems like it's gone back to the original version.

Now, Can I go back to my modified version, or is it all gone?  This is a for a test app so although not crucial, I'd really prefer to not lose it all :)

Thanks

Comment: In this case Dropbox saved my file.  However, I'm concerned that Xcode seems to have reverted back to the original .m and .h for the initial view controller and the initial state of the second view controllers .m file without me doing anything.  Anyone aware of any bugs?  I'm going to turn off source control for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting an answer here as I hate to leave things with no answers.  Dropbox sorted my problem as I had a backup copy of everything, and I am yet to find out what went wrong.  I'm now using a combination of Dropbox and a GIT repo to keeps things save.